# Multiple trackers with dimensions not working

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have multiple tracker IDs dynamically generated. One of them have a dimension, as I don't know which tracker have the dimension configured when generating them I set it for all trackers, like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-47041417-1', 'auto', {'name': 'tracker0'});  
ga('create', 'UA-47041417-2', 'auto', {'name': 'tracker1'});  
ga('tracker0.send', 'pageview', {'dimension1' : 'client1/serviceA'});  
ga('tracker1.send', 'pageview', {'dimension1' : 'client1/serviceA'});
```

Here is the dimension configured for one of the trackers:[image]

And here is the filter info for this tracker:
[image]

It does not work. The hit is being counted on Google Analytics real-time page. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Setup looks right. Maybe it was a lag in the filter being applied to real time?

Comment: Maybe... I gave up and I am using multiple trackers, works fine.